Disable autocomplete but keep suggestions in Bash
I want disable autocomplete (pressing to Tab to complete my command automatically) on my Bash on Linux, but keep the double-Tab shortcut for showing suggestions, so that I can type the rest of the command myself.

Create a file in your home directory named .inputrc and place the following content inside:
"\t": self-insert
"\t\t": possible-completions

Then restart your shell.

The first line overwrites the default binding for Tab to perform the self-insert action (i.e. insert a literal 'tab' character)
The second line adds a new binding for double-tapping Tab which performs the possible-completions action (print possible completions)

Note that this has a slight caveat - the insertion of a \t character when the Tab key is pressed is buffered (delayed) while the shell waits to see whether or not you double press the Tab key.
you can find the list of available actions using bind -P in a Bash shell.
Sources -

how to disable double tab to show available commands in bash
Bash bind documentation

